# linux upstart does not start sidekiq

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, sidekiq, upstart

I am trying to make sidekiq service with this piece of code:

```
description "Sidekiq Background Worker"

respawn
respawn limit 3 30

normal exit 0 TERM

instance $index

script
exec /bin/bash <<'EOT'
  cd /var/app/current
  exec bundle exec sidekiq -i ${index} -e production
EOT
end script
```

On Amazon EC2 instance with ElasticBeanstalk:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2015.09"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2015.09"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2015.09:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2015.09
```

When I start service it says:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-46-88 init]$ sudo start kiq index=0
kiq (0) start/running, process 2531
```

But the thing is that there is no such process anymore when I try to `ps aux | grep it` also calling:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-46-88 init]$ sudo initctl list
kiq stop/waiting
```

shows that it has stopped.

And I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.
Anyone solved this issue?

Also saying that with just executing in terminal `exec bundle exec sidekiq -i ${index} -e production` works for loading up sidekiq

Comment: What's in the logfile?